# Adding google-services.json hangs visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, google-play-services

I'm trying to get FireBase Push Notification to work. I'm now at the point in the description where google-services.json is added to the project. As soon as I set it's "build action" to "googleservicesjson" Visual Studio goes into a never ending loop and all interaction with it come to a grinding halt.

Comment: Is the `.json` file valid? Can you open it in VS *before* setting the build action to `GoogleServicesJson`? Also the `MSBuild` `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets` processes the file at build time, so try building from the cmdline to see if you are getting: `Error: Failed to Read or Deserialize GoogleServicesJson file: google-services.json`

Comment: After waiting for about 4 minutes Visual Studio started responding again. The same happens when I clean the solution and build it again.

Comment: The json is valid and readable.

Comment: Report it as a bug (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com)... I have zero issues with those type of `.json` files myself, there really should be no Xamarin-based actions happening against those files until build time...

Comment: Hey Paul. I have the exact same issue on my machine. After I add the item group in the csproj file, my VS starts to hang. 
When I revert the change in the csproj file , it starts working , but I'm getting "Java execution error code 2". So I don't know what to do in this case.
I started thinking that me only have that issue.

Comment: I've had some weird errors from java too but rebuilding or cleaning and building my project has so far solved these problems

Comment: Take a look here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/250165/#Comment_250165. I've solved it for now using a T4 template that uses the json from Firebase (without the build action set to 'googleservicesjson' but 'none').